# move object along measured curve in manim

Tags: manim

I'm trying to find a sensible way to move an `Mobject` along a path defined by the n-length vectors `ts,xs,ys,(zs)`.

The solution I have now is by using `ParametricFunction` and `MoveAlongPath`. I can then define a rate function to make sure the timing adds up. This is extremely backwards and not quite reliable in my experience.

I feel like I'm probably missing some builtin function but I can't find it.

```py
# This function takes a path defined by arrays and returns a function
# ts is assumed to be strictly increasing
def manim_curve(ts,xs,ys):
    ts,xs,ys = map(np.array,(ts,xs,ys))

    # Calculate the total distance traveled over the curve
    dist = np.cumsum(np.abs(np.diff(xs+1j*ys,prepend=0))) 

    # Normalize to a time range of [0,1]
    nts   = ts   / ts[-1]
    ndist = dist / dist[-1]

    # Create a function that can be passed `ParametricFunction`
    def f(t):
        n = np.abs(nts-t).argmin() # Find index from t
        return (xs[n],ys[n],0)
    
    # Create a rate function for `MoveAlongPath`
    def rate(t):
        n = np.abs(nts-t).argmin() # Find index from t
        return ndist[n]
    
    # Create manim curve
    curve = ParametricFunction(function=f)

    return curve,rate

# Animation class to move along a discretely defined path  
class MoveAlongMeasuredPath(MoveAlongPath):
    def __init__(self,object,ts,xs,ys,**kwargs):
        ts,xs,ys   = map(np.array,(ts,xs,ys))
        curve,rate = manim_curve(ts,xs,ys)
        super().__init__(object,curve,
                         run_time  = ts[-1],
                         rate_func = rate,
                         **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug a little deeper in the code and realized there is a simple solution. The class below is only a slight alteration of the `MoveAlongPath` class source code:

```py
class MoveAlongTXYZPath(Animation):
    def __init__(
        self,
        mobject: Mobject,
        ts:NDArray,
        points:NDArray,
        is_sorted:bool=False,
        suspend_mobject_updating: bool = False,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        assert np.all(ts>=0), "no negative t_values allowed"
        assert len(ts)==len(points), "vectors have to be the same length"

        # Sort if unsorted in t
        if not is_sorted:
            ts,points = map(np.array,zip(*sorted([*zip(ts,points)])))
        self.points = points
        run_time = np.max(ts)
        self.alphas = ts/run_time
        super().__init__( mobject, 
                          suspend_mobject_updating=suspend_mobject_updating,
                          run_time=run_time,
                          rate_func=linear,
                          **kwargs)

    def interpolate_mobject(self, alpha: float) -> None:
        index = np.searchsorted(self.alphas,alpha)
        point = self.points[index]
        self.mobject.move_to(point)
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to move an Mobject along a path defined by the n-length vectors ts,xs,ys,(zs) is to use the ParametricFunction and MoveAlongPath functions. This will allow you to define a path using the vectors and then move the Mobject along that path. It is a reliable and straightforward way to achieve this.

Comment: This is what I've been doing, but by default this messes up the timing. The `MoveAlongMeasuredPath` class I wrote gets around that but it seems a bit backwards to me. I'm also not entirely sure if this does get the timing correct.